# How can I make iconimages that are present in the root directory page also appear in another directory?

Tags: javascript, html, mouseover

I inherited a customer after their programmer passed away. They have 4 commercial sites running what I believe is Adobe Go Live code from what I’ve found on Google.

This works perfectly as long as all .asp scripts and the images directory is off the web’s root directory. I needed to move the ‘store’ scripts under a ‘store’ sub directory. When I run the default page that is in the root directory the buttons appear with icons in them. When I click one of the buttons for a page where the asp lives under the ‘store’ directory, none of  the buttons have images in them anymore. I know Nothing about Javascript. I’m sure for someone who know it this is a quick dumb fix. Any help would be appreciated.

Additional Information:
I've narrowed the bug down to the path to the directory where the images are located need to change. If I copy the images directory under each of the sub directories, it works fine. I would really prefer not to have 4 copies of every picture on the system.

Thanks in advance and here’s a partial sample source code

```
<HEAD>
<script src="js_files/primary.js"></script>
<csactiondict>
<script><!--
CSInit[CSInit.length] = new Array    (CSILoad,/*CMP*/'button',/*URL*/'buttons/hp2.gif',/*URL*/'buttons/hp2.gif',/*URL*/'','Home     Page');
CSInit[CSInit.length] = new Array    (CSILoad,/*CMP*/'button2',/*URL*/'buttons/mv1.gif',/*URL*/'buttons/mv2.gif',/*URL*/'','But    ton2Text');
CSInit[CSInit.length] = new Array    (CSILoad,/*CMP*/'button3',/*URL*/'buttons/sev1.gif',/*URL*/'buttons/sev2.gif',/*URL*/'','B    uttons3sText');
// --></script>
</csactiondict>
</HEAD>

<BODY>

<csobj w="96" h="18" t="Button" st="Home Page" ht="buttons/hp2.gif">
<a href="#" onmouseover="return CSIShow(/*CMP*/'button',1)" onmouseout="return CSIShow    (/*CMP*/'button',0)" onclick="return CSButtonReturn()"><img     src="buttons/hp2.gif" width="96" height="18" name="button" border="0" alt="Home Page"></a>
</csobj>
<br>
<img height="2" width="108" src="images/spacer.gif" border="0" alt="Spacer">
<br>

<csobj w="96" h="18" t="Button" st="Button1Text" ht="buttons/hmc2.gif"><a     href="Link1.asp" onmouseover="return CSIShow(/*CMP*/'button35',1)" onmouseout="return     CSIShow(/*CMP*/'button35',0)" onclick="return CSButtonReturn()">
<img src="buttons/hmc1.gif" width="96" height="18" name="button3" border="0"     alt="Button3AltText"></a>
</csobj>
<br>

<img height="8" width="108" src="images/spacer.gif" border="0" alt="Spacer">
<br>
<csobj w="96" h="18" t="Button" st="Link2Text" ht="buttons/mv2.gif"><a     href="Link2.asp" onmouseover="return CSIShow(/*CMP*/'button2',1)" onmouseout="return     CSIShow(/*CMP*/'button2',0)" onclick="return CSButtonReturn()"><img src="buttons/mv1.gif"     width="96" height="18" name="button2" border="0" alt="Button2Text"></a></csobj>
</BODY>
```

Comment: Bad luck inherting that... mighten it be easier to rewrite the rollovers using CSS than fix that?

Comment: -1 This needs a more descriptive title.  I'm trying to come up with one but can't because this post basically says "I have no idea what the problem is come fix it for me."

Comment: I concur that the title needs improvement, and I have to second that I can't extract one all too quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you replace all references to `buttons/` with `/buttons/` (add a slash at the front) it should work for pages in subdirectories.

so

```
CSInit[CSInit.length] = new Array    (CSILoad,/*CMP*/'button',/*URL*/'buttons/hp2.gif',/*URL*/'buttons/hp2.gif',/*URL*/'','Home     Page');
```

would become

```
CSInit[CSInit.length] = new Array    (CSILoad,/*CMP*/'button',/*URL*/'/buttons/hp2.gif',/*URL*/'/buttons/hp2.gif',/*URL*/'','Home     Page');
```

and

```
<img src="buttons/hmc1.gif" width="96" height="18" name="button3" border="0"     alt="Button3AltText"></a>
```

would become

```
<img src="/buttons/hmc1.gif" width="96" height="18" name="button3" border="0"     alt="Button3AltText"></a>
```

and so on. You would only need one `buttons` directory at the root of the host.

Your editor should have a way to "Replace All" to make applying these changes less painful.